# Upgrade to Big Sur Beta 3 Broke Brew Build system

Tags: xcode, homebrew, beta, big-sur

Today I upgraded to Big Sur Beta3 and I cannot install anything with Brew. I get the error:

```
Error: Your Xcode (11.6) is too outdated.
Please update to Xcode 12.0 (or delete it).
Xcode can be updated from:
  https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Error: Could not find an SDK that supports macOS 11.0.
You may have have an outdated or incompatible Xcode.
Homebrew found the following SDKs in the Xcode install:
  10.15
```

I can safely Ignore first error as I have tried everything I state here with XCode 12 Beta2 yielding the same results. The second one which is actually the issue I get seems to come from name changes that makes this Beta to be 11.0 instead of 10.16.

I have [read blog post](https://eclecticlight.co/2020/07/21/big-sur-is-both-10-16-and-11-0-its-official/) proposing setting special environment variable and I set as below but still does not work.

```
export SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=1
```

Any pointer or help is appreciated

Comment: Xcode 11.6 will definitively not work. Can you switch to Xcode 12, try again and add the error you get (instead of the one you have now)? Otherwise people will just recommend to use Xcode 12.

Comment: As said in the post, both 11.6 and 12 Beta 2 are not working

Comment: The problem seems to be numbering as far as I understand the message. So the setting of `SYSTEM_VERSION_COMPAT=1` seems to not having the said effect somehow

Comment: Sounds like something that should be reported to Apple via the feedback tool.

Comment: I wonder if Apple actually tests their Beta before providing updates. Yes I know Beta are not yet stable but some things seems too obvious for me. I might be wrong though

Comment: I always enjoy stupid downvotes, i.e downvote providing no reason. Neither it helps to make the question better, not do the downvoter get anything. It's sheer waste of clicks lol!

Comment: You are using a beta product and seem to expect production stability. Some people might habe issues with that leading to downvotes.

Comment: Also the error message clearly says „update to Xcode 12“. So this is something you can and should do, and then post the error you get with Xcode 12 (which then might give an idea about what else is wrong/missing).

Comment: I have XCode 12 beta 2 and XCode 11 installed side by side. And I have tried them. All I get is both errors in XCode 11 and the last error in XCode 12

Comment: I'd put this in as an answer but my Mac running Big Sur is currently packed away and I can't get it out just to confirm the exact path of the 10.16 SDK.. The problem you are having is due to Apple confusing the issue by calling Big Sur both macOS 10.16 and macOS 11. Now you have XCode 12 installed you will find the SDK installed as "10.16". Creat a symlink to that SDK called "11.0" and your problem will go away.

Comment: I had to install XCode 12 Beta 3 in addition to Commandline tools of the same version. Not sure but it seems Beta3 does not smoothly work with Beta2 tools, at least that was my case

Comment: i'll find time to test your solution with XCode 11

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Same thing happened to me, you need to install the most recent Beta version of command line tools as well as the matching XCode 12 Beta. The same thing also happens with git and other things added by the download https://developer.apple.com/download/more/?=xcode

Comment: I had to install XCode 12 Beta 3 in addition to Commandline tools

Comment: WARNING: Only follow instructions in this comment if you are really confident.  I simply mode a copy of the MacOS 11 SDK (in the Xcode Beta), and modified some of the variables in the SDKSettings.plist file. This was able to confuse brew into thinking the SDK had the same version as the OS. (I did this with one of the beta SDKs, which brew wasn't detecting properly)

Answer (score 4):

Yep, was broken till I installed Xcode 12.2 Beta 3 / Xcode 12.2 Command line tools Beta 3. Not surprised, this happens every year. I've just received a notification that Xcode Beta 2 Command Line Tools will be automatically installed tonight but I already only have Beta 3 installed.  It's a BETA and it's buggy.

Also, Homebrew's response:

```
$ brew doctor
```

> **Warning:** You are using macOS 11.0. We do not provide support for this
> pre-release version. You will encounter build failures with some
> formulae. Please create pull requests instead of asking for help on
> Homebrew's Gihub, Discourse, Twitter or IRC. You are responsible for
> resolving any issues you experience while you are running this
> pre-release version.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by doing:
`sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app`.

Comment: Xcode 12 has been released, and the command line tools can be dowloaded now, but I'm still getting the error. I tried this command to no avail.

Comment: did you delete old XCode?

Comment: Also just checked there is `macOS Big Sur Beta 7 11.0`. Try upgrading to that one and see if it works! I have Beta 6 of Both XCode and MacOS and I have faced no issue!