# Homebrew: Your CLT does not support macOS 11.0

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, big-sur

I recently upgraded to macOS Big Sur developer Beta 8, when I do `brew install jenv` I get the error **Homebrew: Your CLT does not support macOS 11.0**. I am using CommandLine tools GM version.  Tried to reinstall it couple of times, nothing worked so far. Here is the complete error

```
Error: Your CLT does not support macOS 11.0.
It is either outdated or was modified.
Please update your CLT or delete it if no updates are available.
Error: An exception occurred within a child process:
  SystemExit: exit
```

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/396818/upgrade-to-big-sur-beta-3-broke-brew-build-system/396926#396926

Answer (score 72, accepted):

We can fix this by downloading [Command Line Tools for Xcode 12.3](https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_12.3/Command_Line_Tools_for_Xcode_12.3.dmg) from Apple website

Comment: It's probably worth noting that in order to download the package directly from Apple's website, one needs to be a member of Apple Developer Program.

Answer (score 222):

Simplest solution that worked when upgrading to Big Sur. A clean install may not require the solution below. There is inconsistency with the way CLT is upgraded to 12.2.

```
sudo rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools
sudo xcode-select --install
```

Worked with the following versions (post-install)

```
❯ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
Xcode 12.2
Build version 12B45b

❯ pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
package-id: com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
version: 12.2.0.0.1.1603499215
volume: /
location: /
install-time: 1605632122
groups: com.apple.FindSystemFiles.pkg-group

Big Sur
11.0.1 (20B29)
```

Comment: After doing this, I was able to `brew upgrade ruby-build --fetch-HEAD`.

Comment: Perfect, only solution I could find elsewhere - Fixed brew with: Upgraded: gradle 6.7 -> 6.7.1
jenkins 2.266 -> 2.267
node 15.2.0 -> 15.2.1
imagemagick 7.0.10-38 -> 7.0.10-39

Comment: Warning to anyone doing this on a slow connection. I did the rm and then `sudo xcode-select --install` and it began downloading software with "5 hours 15 minutes remaining". Be careful if you're on a slow connection like me before embarking on this (I have not found a solution, still waiting)

Answer (score 8):

Currently Brew is being updated incrementally to support MacOS Big Sur. You can follow the progress in the [corresponding GitHub issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/issues/7857).

There is very little breakage in the core for Big Sur on intel and most of the work is to get core features working on the pre-release Apple Silicon hardware. Most people on Intel hardware and not the DTK should be ready now during beta or very soon after release of the initial version of the OS.

Comment: Excellent resource - please roll back my edit if it’s too cautious.

Comment: The referenced git issue is about Apple Silicon, not macOS 11.

Answer (score 8):

### Xcode is installed?

If you installed the **Command Line Tools (CLT)** and later installed **Xcode**, make sure the **CLT** installed beforehand are removed `[sudo] rm -rf /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools` and inside Xcode preferences `Locations` the CLT is set to Xcode.

> There is no need to install any beta version if you have the newest Xcode installed.
>
> > Version 12.2 (12B45b)

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to add, that the homebrew project has a tool to tell you how to fix Xcode tools related errors. Not all errors by "doctor" need to be fixed, but the ones relating to `xcode-select` and `softwareupdate` will fix tools issues on supported versions.

For the window while an OS is in pre-release and released-but-not-yet-supported, you will have to resort to answers like the ones here to manually fix the automated setup process.